# Why mysql add a read lock to myisam engine table when select data?

Tags: mysql, locking, myisam

Why mysql add a read lock to myisam engine table when select data?

On the official manual,it only mention that innodb has a default isolation.And we know the myisam engine does not support transaction.But why the mysql add a read lock to the selecting table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a table were modified while a query was reading from it, the read query might return incorrect results. To prevent this, MyISAM uses a lock* to prevent writes from being made to a table while any other threads are reading from that table. This lock doesn't prevent other read queries, though - any number of threads can share the lock.

Tables are also locked while a query is writing to them. This uses a different type of lock to prevent any other writes *or reads* from taking place on that table.

Comment: Thanks.But the I can not find information about the read lock (when query data) on official manual.Is it a sql standard?

Comment: The SQL standard doesn't talk about implementation quirks, like how MyISAM needs table locks to work its dark magic. Honestly, MyISAM is really not worth using because of things like this, it's an engine that was good enough for MySQL 1.0 but is very dated by modern standards. Use InnoDB whenever possible. It supports transactions, has a journal to roll-back safely in case of a server crash, and a lot more.

Comment: Well,you mean that we can not find the official context about the read lock for myisam(even myisam engine's information is little).And I should give up use the myisam engine.

Comment: The documentation is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html#internal-table-level-locking

Comment: That says mysql myisam will set a talble lock (read lock) for the read operation."Select" is a read operation,so mysql will set the read lock (as table level lock) on the myisam table.So other write operation should wait for it finish because the manual says "If there are no locks on the table".That's it?